# Rails 3/3.1 and I18n: Validation hits when switching between languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The database is seeded with values in english language and format, e.g., :hourlyrate => 20.90. On first start (language is english by default), the input form displays the content of the field correctly. I can modify and save, no problem. 
If I switch to german, the number is displayed correctly as 20,90. If I edit anything on this form, I can not save again, as the validation catches the number as not being valid.

My question is, do I have to perform corrections in my controller before saving, or did I miss some built-in function of Rails?

Relevant parts of the code

Helper:

```
def my_number_with_precision(value)
  if value 
    # value
    number_with_precision(value, :precision => 2)
  end  
end
```

Validation:

```
validates :hourlyrate, :numericality => { :greater_or_equal_than => 0, :message => " is an invalid number or below zero" }
```

Form:

```
<div class="input">
  <%= f.text_field :hourlyrate, :value => my_number_with_precision(f.object.hourlyrate) %>
</div>
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails-i18n'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with one of the following solutions - language specific code:

```
def parse_i18n(value)
  if I18n.locale = 'de' 
    value.gsub(',', '.')
  else
    value
  end
end

def parse_i18n(value)
  value.gsub(I18n.t("number.currency.format.unit"),'').
        gsub(I18n.t("number.currency.format.delimiter"), '').
        gsub(I18n.t("number.currency.format.separator"), '.') 
end
```